# SSH user response prompt

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

We currently have several users that are using the admin user when logging into a server via SSH. They all have their own users but unfortunately they still occasionally use the admin one. We can lock this down of course and take action to make sure that user is never used, but I'm looking to see if there is a way to force each login to enter a reason why they are using that user, before they can login and access the server whenever they use the admin user.

This way we can have an easy way to compare access log files with employee names and the reason why they are using that user.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Make the admin password random. You will then have 2 options. Option 1: use `sudo`. This will log the users `sudo`ing as admin. Option 2: use ssh key-based authentication for admin user. Everyone will need to register their ssh-key to this admin user.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do.

Register everyone's ssh public key into admin user's `authorized_keys`. In each entry, set the environment `EMPLOYEE` to the `employeename`. This will require that `PermitUserEnviroment` be set to `yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. A sample entry should look like below.

```
environment="EMPLOYEE=employee1" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1y.....EU88ovYKg4GfclWGCFYTuw8==
```

Now that we have an environment variable named `EMPLOYEE`, we can write a simple script to ask for the reason.

Create a file `/etc/profile.d/reason.sh`. The file does not need to be executable as it will be sourced.

```
if [[ $(whoami) = "admin" ]]; then
    read -p "Please specify the reason for logging in as $USER user: " reason
    if [ -z "$reason" ]; then
        logout
    fi
fi
```

Now you have `$EMPLOYEE` and `$reason` to log.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought

```
#!/bin/bash

# if the user tries Ctrl+C to avoid this check
trap INT no_shell_for_you

no_shell_for_you() { exec /bin/false; }

read -p "Your username please: " username

if getent password "$username" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "Welcome, $username"
    # log $username somewhere
    exec /bin/bash -l
else
    no_shell_for_you
fi
```

1. Save that as ~admin_user/bin/get_real_user.sh
2. Add /full/path/to/admin_user/bin/get_real_user.sh to `/etc/shells`
3. Do `sudo chsh -s /full/path/to/admin_user/bin/get_real_user.sh admin_user`

This is untested. Test *thoroughly* before step 3.

Comment: Thank you! That helped me get into the right direction to find an answer.

Comment: This is open to false representation. Any user can pretend to be another.